# Controlling re-renders in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

I have been given the task to use a react lifecycle method *other* than `shouldComponentUpdate()` to control re-rendering of a component. Just like how `shouldComponentUpdate()` can prevent re-renders if you return false, I should be able to use one of the other lifecycle methods (like `componentWillUpdate()`, `componentDidUpdate()` maybe?) to prevent re-renders if the state is the same as the previous state.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I have this type of a setup:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      someStateProperty: "abcd"
    };
  }

  // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //   if (this.state.someStateProperty !== nextState.someStateProperty)
  //     return true;
  //   return false;
  // }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <input
        value={this.state.text}
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code, I am updating `this.state.text` while keeping `this.state.someProperty` the same.

`shouldComponentUpdate()` is called every time there is a call to `this.setState` and returns false due to the comparison inside, preventing the re-rendering of the input component because there is no change in `this.state.someProperty`.
This prevents the `render()` function from running again and I do not get render logged in the console.

So is there another lifecycle method that can replicate this sort of behavior?

I have also created a sandbox/playground of it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-shadow-xld6h8).

Comment: There is no reason to use another lifecycle method. You could just change the logic `return nextProps.someStateProperty !== this.state.someStateProperty || nextProps.text !== this.state.text`. However if you simply don't want to re-render the component if no state changes or prop changes are made you should probably just inherit from [`PureComponent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/PureComponent) rather then [`Component`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component).

Comment: I've suggested `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `PureComponent` but my senior insists that there is another way/lifecycle method.

Comment: Maybe they are talking about invoking [`forceUpdate()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#forceupdate) somewhere, but that seems like a strange thing to do in this scenario.

Comment: The example they gave me was similar to the one I have given. They said that I should be able to not re-render if after calling `setState` , the state didn't actually change.